# Chat redirecting to A51? (2013)

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

May be a problem on my end, but chat.SE of all sites (SO, MSE, SE) is pushing me to Area51.

Can anyone confirm? (hard to check in chat when you can't get in chat)

Additional notes:

While the hotlist still works fine

[image]

inbox notifications seem to also be not working properly.

[image]

Comment: Happening here. Actually, I was trying to confirm a problem where I was not able to load stackoverflow.com. It seems there was an HTTP 500 error. I tried to get to Chat, and it redirected me to Area 51. Then I tried to Ask Question on Meta, and I had a redirect loop (Welcome George, you are logged in). I cleared cookies for StackOverflow and now I can log in.

Comment: I can confirm that it was happening, momentarily. the main stackoverflow was also throwing runtime exceptions. All fixed now.

Comment: Confirmed for me.

Comment: Happened for a bit. Might have something to do with the uncaught exception on SO. Inbox issue not reproduced, but I didn't check when the other things were bugging out for me.

Comment: @mnel, I still am not able to get to Chat. Still have the redirect to Area51. I tried to clear Cache, and that did not help.

Comment: Reproduced. I can't get to chat.stackexchange or chat.stackoverflow, at all. Redirected to area51

Comment: Still redirecting here as well

Comment: We had some sort of Database server issue, we are currently trying to figure out what happened.

Comment: @KyleBrandt ack ack. Just wanted to toss stones in the water when the TL wouldn't load.

Comment: @Kyle, Do we get to hear more about what went wrong? Or will it be something like *"Super Bowl Power Failure Still Largely Unexplained"*? (just kidding)

Comment: I hit this too, for about 5 minutes.  Everything went down and chat redirected to Area 51.  Appears to be working now.

Comment: @Seth thanks for the update, but you may notice the above `status-completed` on the post?

Comment: @jcolebrand Ah, no I didn't notice.  Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So apparently SQL server was tired of dishing out our data and decided to take a break.

[stackstatus.net](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/42405170951/database-issue-feb-5th-2013) has the details.