# Chat is redirecting to Area 51 (2023 edition)

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, area-51, regression

Any https://chat.stackexchange.com URL redirects to https://area51.stackexchange.com.

This started a few minutes ago (as of this posting).

This occurs for all three chat servers (chat.stackoverflow, chat.stackexchange, and chat.meta.stackexchange)

Comment: How does this _happen_?

Comment: Hey wait, [this has happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299890/going-to-chat-stackexchange-com-takes-me-to-area-51?rq=1)! Darn it, Haney!

Comment: We're looking into it. apologies, y'all.

Comment: And [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166411/294691).

Comment: Wouldn't it be funny if this was to do with the other meta post about a51 chat parents and a botched fix :p

Comment: It's back now. We'll have someone write up what happened in a bit. :)

Comment: [Related prior issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385568/377214) that occurred last week

Comment: Apparently some hours prior to this issue occurring, some [authentication cookies were invalidated](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62793834#62793834) making it impossible for bots to post chat messages during that time.

Comment: this happened to me too; and also  - each time I log in, I have to log in many times (3 or 4 times) to diff sites; idk if it's related but;

Comment: **note** I know the site was "down" or "read only" before, for some hour/s; idk maybe related as well  oh btw; `good luck to mods!` no stress :) have a good day!

Comment: I slept through that - its more of a dev/SRE problem, than a mod problem :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To quote a friend:

> I broke it. I just unbroke it. Sorry!
> - [Haney, 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299891/209031)

Also, the reason for the weird redirect is we ***attempt to resolve retired site names*** during an `OnActionExecuting` hook that handles a `catch` and *redirects back to Area 51*.

i.e. https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/ → https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone

But that handles too many thrown exceptions and kind of a silly way to re-route traffic.  Still would've been broken anyway, but we'll shore this up to make it a little more obvious to the end user what's happening if errors arise.

Comment: So whenever a site is retired, chat will break for few hours until dev manually change it?

Comment: So you're telling me that your fallback for having a site break is... _redirecting to its Area 51 page???_

Comment: Oh, in case it's been retired :p

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars, no, the error was unrelated, just the way that error manifests as a redirect is the additional odd part that can be handled even better.